# How to export a function and an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of nationalities in and a function that returns the name of nationality from the CountryCode. Both of them are in a file called `nationality.js`.

Here is the function

```
map_code_to_nationality = (code) => {
    return nationalities.filter((data) => {
        return data.CountryCode == code
    })[0].Nationality
}
```

Now I want to export the function and the list of nationality (i.e. an array of nationalities). I tried to export both of them like this.

```
export const map_code_to_nationality
export const nationalities
```

Now if I use function keyword for map_code_to_nationality in the export statement the editor shows a syntax error and the export statements stated above gives an error in the  browser that

> Attempted import error: 'map_code_to_nationality' is not exported from
>   '../../static_data/nationality_list'.

I have imported it in other file like this

```
import { map_code_to_nationality, nationalities } from '../../static_data/nationality_list'
```

How do I use both the function and array by exporting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export them in an object, like so:

```
export const obj = {
  map_code_to_nationality,
  nationalities
}
```

And then use it in your import like so

```
import { obj } from '../../static_data/nationality_list';

obj.map_code_to_nationality
obj.nationalities
```

Alternatively, if you want somewhat more elegant syntax (with default export):

```
export default {
  map_code_to_nationality,
  nationalities
}
```

And then in the driver code, use the following:

```
import obj from '../../static_data/nationality_list';

obj.map_code_to_nationality
obj.nationalities
```

Comment: When using the alternative way it gives an error that Export 'map_code_to_nationality' is not defined.

Comment: Try `export default { map_code_to_nationality, nationalities }`. @BhaumikBhatt

Comment: I've added @Andy's suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Do I have to add any keyword before the function? Because after using this same alternate way it is giving the error that map_code_to_nationality is not defined in nationality.js

Comment: Yes! Never declare functions without var/const/let. Just add var in front of that and you'll be set.

Comment: why prefixing them using var/const/let is required? I have been using the functions without any of these keyword as prefix. Is it bad coding practice?

Comment: You were right using let as a prefix combining with the elegant method you gave me solved the problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you can do :

```
export {map_code_to_nationality, nationalities};
```

and then use them in other modules, like :

```
import { map_code_to_nationality, nationalities } from '../../static_data/nationality_list';
```

Answer (score -1):

//In module.js add below code

```
export function multiply() {
    return 2 * 3;
}
```

// Consume the module in calc.js

```
import { multiply } from './modules.js';

const result = multiply();

console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

// Module.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Module</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="module" src="./calc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its a design pattern same code can be found below, please use a live server to test it else you will get CORS error

https://github.com/rohan12patil/JSDesignPatterns/tree/master/Structural%20Patterns/module

Here you can also export an array as well, but remember to import it from the module

Comment: How is this even related to the question?

Comment: @Dragos Strugar Please read the question above, which says how to export a function & an array, if you can export a function then you can certainly export an array